# Fix "Variable is used before being assigned" error

Tags: typescript

From my code snippet below,

```js
import { STS } from 'aws-sdk'

const sts = new STS({
    region: 'us-east-1'
});
let accessKeyId: string
let secretAccessKey: string

sts.assumeRole(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        accessKeyId = data.Credentials?.AccessKeyId || '';
        secretAccessKey = data.Credentials?.SecretAccessKey || '';
    }
}); 

console.log(accessKeyId);
console.log(secretAccessKey);
```

VS code says "Variable 'accessKeyId' is used before being assigned." I need to access these two variables outside the `assumeRole()` sdk call...how can I make sure the variables are set at that time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accessKeyId` is being used before it's assigned, because for typescript there is no guarantee that your logs get run before the callback is executed. Without knowing what `assumeRole` does, the fact that it takes a callback means it's probably asynchronous, so there will almost certainly be some delay.

As such, if you need to use `accessKeyId`, you should do it once it has been assigned after it has been set in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Work in the return block so that it will only process once it the data is returned.

```
{
if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
} else {

    accessKeyId = data.Credentials?.AccessKeyId || '';
    secretAccessKey = data.Credentials?.SecretAccessKey || '';
//work here
    }
});
```

Suggestion 2 put into a function that waits async to finish before using the varible

Comment: so I just need to wrap the `assumeRole()` call inside an `async` function?

Comment: No you need the data back first before calling the information otherwise you will always get an error of nil or undefined

Comment: Just update where you need from inside .assumeRole, call a function from there that needs updating